# How to associate Click to Form Control as was previously done to ActiveX Control?

Tags: macos, excel, vba

In Excel 2010 for Windows, I associated a Click event to an ActiveX Control.  In Excel 2011 for Mac, I understand I must use Form Controls rather than ActiveX Controls.  How do I associate a Click with a Form Control command button?  I don't seem to be able to get at the Properties of a Form Control as I previously did with an ActiveX Control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that Mac Form Controls act like Windows ones. When you first create the button, you'll see the Assign Macro dialog. If you've already created the macro, you can select it then:

[image]

If you want to assign the macro later, you need to get the Assign Macro dialog. In Windows, you'd right-click like this:

[image]

I'm realizing this is not my most helpful answer ever, but hopefully it's good enough.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It got me going in the right direction.  I did some work many years ago in VBA, and am now trying to remember it - and learn the Mac.